# OpenX : mySql VS PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have been using [OpenX's AdServer](http://www.openx.org/ad-server) with `mySql` as a backend, and since OpenX allows one to choose between `mysql` and `postgres`, I was wondering if anyone ever used `Postgres` and wished to talk about their experience with it here.

Also, is there anyone who maybe tried using OpenX with both and can offer a comparison between the databases ?

I am asking this question because I was having some trouble recently with mySql because some tables crashed occasionally and proved problematic because of the overhead they generated; and as a consequence of this, Statistics where not being generated.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that PostgreSQL is handling complex queries much better than MySQL so if you will be doing some advanced SQL I can recommend PostgreSQL. It is very crash safe.

We moved to PostgreSQL for performance and license reasons. When MySQL was split in one commercial and one open sourced version, 2006 I believe, we turned to PostgreSQL. As Jay states PostgreSQL needs a bit more tuning and you might find it a bit harder to get started compared to MySQL.

// John

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL for OpenXAd Server is not as well supported as MySQL is - for example in OpenXAd 2.8.7 statistics don't work in Postgres. Stick to MySQL with OpenXAd then.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the biggest advantage to MySQL is marketshare.

By that, I mean any program you download which requires a backend database will likely have MySQL support built in.  You run the setup script, and you're golden.  With Postgres, it may or may not have support.  Many applications likely will be able to run on Postgres with very little modification, but then you have to decide whether it's worth the time.

Personally, I'm leaning towards trying more and more Postgres when I get the chance, but I won't spend days and days trying to make something work.  If it doesn't work quickly, I'll just throw it on MySQL.  Of course my applications are small and mainly for personal use.  In a business situation, it might be worth the extra time.

Comment: interesting opinon, but not really related to the question :)